# Japanese character encoding using Shift_JIS in Java

Tags: java, shift-jis

I have a web application which is served using tomcat.

On one of the pages, it allows the users to download a file stored on my file server. The names of most of the files present there are in Japanese. However, when the user downloads the file, the name of the file is garbled. Also, it works differently on different browsers.

The original code is as below:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(absolutePath);
ResponseUtil.download(new String(downloadFileName.getBytes("Shift_JIS"), "ISO-8859-1"), in);
```

e.g., 08_タイヨーアクリス_装置開発_実績表 gets interpreted as 
      08_ƒ^ƒCƒˆ-[ƒAƒNƒŠƒX_‘•’uŠJ”-_ŽÀ-Ñ• in Google Chrome
This problem is due to the presence of '5c' in the file name and seems to be a known problem in Shift_JIS. I want to know the correct way to work around this problem.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the second line of your code? What context is it running in? It looks like the code is taking the file's name in Unicode, encoding that as Shift-JIS, and then trying to decode that Shift-JIS data as if it were ISO-8859-1. Which will likely garble it; that's a character encoding error.

Comment: Basically, the second line of the code will download the file with the Japanese name stored in 'downloadFileName'. The file is downloaded with the garbled name. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: That's because those String conversions are garbling it. What happens if you just do `ResponseUtil.download(downloadFileName, in)`? Where is this code running? Is it a Java applet that's running inside the user's browser? And what is supposed to be in Shift-JIS? Is it the contents of the file? Or are they running a filesystem where the names themselves are Shift-JIS?

Comment: Just 'ResponseUtil.download(downloadFileName, in)' also garbles the text. This code is running in a Servlet. Its not the contents, just the names of the files. Also, the garbled string is different for different browsers.

Comment: Gotcha. It sounds like the browsers are picking the wrong encoding for the HTTP response produced by ResponseUtil, either because the HTTP or HTML headers are indicating the wrong encoding, or they browsers are using heuristics that guess wrong. Or your output is being encoded in the wrong character set. But this is the wrong place to fix that: it happens downstream in the processing pipeline, where the entire response document is encoded and presented to the user. Java Strings can only hold Unicode; trying to re-encode here just adds another error.

Comment: Do you have a link to the API documentation for `ResponseUtil`? I don't see it in recent Tomcat APIs. And is this code running on a public web server somewhere where we could view the results?

Comment: And, backing up a bit, why do you want to use Shift-JIS specifically, as opposed to Unicode? Is that a specific requirement or this applicaton?

Comment: Actually, we are using a Japanese fraemwork called [seasar](http://www.seasar.org/en/) , also the link to [ResponseUtil](http://www.seasar.org/source/browse/sastruts/trunk/sa-struts/src/main/java/org/seasar/struts/util/ResponseUtil.java?r1=530&r2=819&pathrev=848&diff_format=s) . I am sorry but it cannot be hosted on a public server. Also, there is no specific requirement to use Shift_JIS.

Comment: Oh gosh. Well, I think I see the problem: `DownloadUtil.download` sticks the filename as-is in to the Content-Disposition header: `response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+ fileName + "\""`. AFAIK, HTTP Headers only support ASCII, so you need to find out what the workaround for escaping non-ASCII strings specifically for the Content-disposition header is. And there are probably differences in browser behavior for this, too.

Comment: is the above function converting Shift JIS into ISO-8859-1? If yes then obviously there will be a lot of garbage because there's no Japanese character in ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `ResponseUtil.download` method from the "Seasar sastruts" framework you're using is taking the filename you provide and sticking it directly in the `Content-disposition` header of the HTTP response it constructs.

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "\"");
```

As far as I can tell, HTTP and MIME headers only support ASCII characters, so this technique won't work with non-ASCII characters. (If this is the case, I'd consider it a bug in this class that it unconditionally sticks the filename in to the header.) Modifying or trying to re-encode the string before you pass it in won't work, because this encoding is at a different level.

To support non-ASCII characters, the header value needs to be encoded using the [MIME encoded-word technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word). There's no way to do this with that `ResponseUtil` class as it is, because it concatenates the name you provide directly in to a non-encoded-word string.

I think you'll need to rewrite that `download()` method to check for non-ASCII characters in the filename inputs it receives, and use encoded-word encoding on strings that contain them. You'd want it to look something like this, where `some_base64_text` is the actual base-64 encoding of the bytes of your file name encoded as Shift-JIS. (Or use UTF-8 instead.)

```
Content-disposition: =?Shift_JIS?B?some_base64_text?=
```

There's probably a lot of different browser behaviors around this, because they're trying to work around various web servers that are doing it "wrong". But it looks like encoding it this way is a good bet for getting it working and making it portable.

Comment: Though it's kind of surprising to me that a framework developed in Japan would mess this up. Maybe there's something obvious I'm overlooking here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot.
I was able to solve the problem on Chrome using the following:

```
ResponseUtil.download(URLEncoder.encode(downloadFileName, "UTF-8"), in);
```

However, the encoding is still not proper in Firefox and Safari.

In Chrome, the file is named "08_タイヨーアクリス_装置開発_実績表.pdf"
But, on Firefox and Safari, it is named "08_%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A8%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9_%E8%A3%85%E7%BD%AE%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA_%E5%AE%9F%E7%B8%BE%E8%A1%A8.pdf".